# How to customize the OAuthBearerAuthentication for Web api in module-zero-template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate

From the code of the `Startup` method of the *module-zero-template* it is very simple to change the options for the cookie authentication:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAbp();
   
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(AccountController.OAuthBearerOptions);  // I want to change the default AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan value, here
    
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
       ExpireTimeSpan = ...,    // this can be simply changed!
       SlidingExpiration = ..., // this can be simply changed!
       ...
     });
   
    ...
}
```

I am wondering how can I configure *some* of the options for the `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` (see the previous line of code) so that they are consistent with those of the cookie authentication.

The problem is that such configuration options (e.g. `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan` or `AllowInsecureHttp`) are only available in the `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` class.

How can I amend the code above for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is changing `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan` you can basically set [TokenAuthConfiguration](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/c14de8b2c6f65fa9ae5c6c612acc8b4a15451895/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Core/Authentication/JwtBearer/TokenAuthConfiguration.cs).Expiration property for that.

For example: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/c14de8b2c6f65fa9ae5c6c612acc8b4a15451895/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Core/AbpProjectNameWebCoreModule.cs#L53-L63

That options will be used while creating token etc. If you need some more options you may change here:
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/c14de8b2c6f65fa9ae5c6c612acc8b4a15451895/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Core/Controllers/TokenAuthController.cs#L196-L210

Comment: Thank you, but it is just for `module-zero-core-template`. It seems to me it is not available in `module-zero-template`. I will investigate the code and see how to copy it in the the legacy complete.